# unable to insert data in Angular to Laravel API

Tags: php, mysql, angular, laravel-5

working with Angular fronted and Laravel back-end API with MySQL. anyway using Angular form trying to insert data to back-end.I have following codes in Angular,
employees.component.ts

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  insertData(){
    this.dataService.insertData(this.employee).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

data.service.ts

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
  insertData(data){
    return this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1.8000/api/addEmployees', data);
  }
```

employees.components.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="insertData()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Salary</label>
        <input type="text" name="salary" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.salary">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm mt-4">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

and laravel
api.php

```
Route::post('addEmployee','EmployeeController@addEmployee');
```

EmployeeController.php

```
public function addEmployee(Request $request){
        $employee = Employee::create($request->all());
        return response($employee, 201);
    }
```

but when I go to insert data using form following errors are coming in the console -

`zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://127.0.0.1.8000/api/addEmployees net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`
`ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://127.0.0.1.8000/api/addEmployees", ok: false, …}`

how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: Probably your endpoint has a dot instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addEmployees

Comment: need more explain what did you mean?

Comment: he means between your IP and Port you have a full stop `.` it should be a colon `:`

Comment: now got following error msg also `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addEmployees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: You should set Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Here is a cors package for Laravel: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: already, done this. but error is still here

Comment: Have you published cors like in the config section? Do you have config/cors.php?